# Solve equation {exponential *prod exponential(ln)}

Tags: matlab, equation, equation-solving

I want to solve  a  equation in MATLAB with fsolve

I'm trying to do that:

```
function F = root2d(P); 

lambda = 2*10^-4;
th = -40:-1:-106;
PL1 = 10471285.480509; % (mw)
p1 = 10;
p2 = 6 ; 
p3 = 8 ; 
al = 2.5;
T = 10.^(th./10);
r = (p1*PL1^(-1)./T).^(1/al);
R = (p2*PL1^(-1)./T).^(1/al);
syms P
c = (lambda.*pi.*(R.^2));
j = 1:3;
D = zeros(3,67);
for k = 1:numel(j)
    F(1) = (prod(D(k,:)==exp(P(1).*c.*(log(P(1)).^k/factorial(k))))).*exp(-(lambda*P(1).*pi.*(r.^2)))-P;
end
fun = @root2d;
P0 = 0;
P = fsolve(fun,P0)
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in this code. I will help you with the most tricky.

It is identified using [rubberduck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Let me exemplify it by explaining your code to you.

Starting from the top you define a function called `root2d`, which returns some object `F`, then in this function you define alot of constants. With these cosntants defined, you can define your symbolic function `F`, which we earlier saw was the output of the function. Continuing in this function, `root2d`, you now create a function handle `fun` to `root2d`, and then in the last line you call `fsolve` to solve `fun`.

Did you see the error?

`fsolve` calls `fun` which is a function handle to `root2d`. Thus `fsolve` calls `root2d`. Running `root2d` MATLAB comes across a new `fsolve` which calls `root2d`. I.e. `root2d` will be pushed unto the stack over and over again.

This is solved by taking the last three lines out of the function, and then running them from another script or from the terminal.

Doing so results in a new error:

> Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are
>   not compatible with the size of the right side.
>
> Error in `sym/privsubsasgn` (line 1085)
>   `L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);`
>
> Error in `sym/subsasgn` (line 922)
>   `C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});`
>
> Error in `SO` (line 18)
>       `F(1) = (prod(D(k,:)==exp(P(1).*c.*(log(P(1)).^k/factorial(k))))).*exp(-(lambda*P(1).*pi.*(r.^2)))-P;`
>
> Error in `fsolve` (line 242)
>               `fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});`
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot
>       continue.

I.e. you have to ensure that your objective function, `F(1) =...` is correctly written.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, Camille, I am new in this forum, my goal is to explain, already you find I write@ scrappedcola instead of @ Nicky Mattsson.my goal is just to solve the equation

Comment: @ Nicky Mattsson:  term2 = for k=1:numel(j) (prod(D(k,:)==exp(P(1).*c.*(log(P(1)).^k/factorial(k))))) end
term1= exp(-(lambda*P(1).*pi.*(r.^2)))
when th = -40 
Error using fsolve (line 269)
FSOLVE requires all values returned by functions to be of data type double.
but when th is a vector (1*67)double
Error in fsolve (line 230)
        fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
Caused by: Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
`